# errorformat for Java junit output

Tags: errorformat, filetype-java

I am trying to get VIM to jump to the file listed in the error.  So the following is the error.

```
|| 1) test01(ErrorTest0)
|| java.lang.NullPointerException
||  at Line.equals(Line.java:43)
||  at ErrorTest0.test01(ErrorTest0.java:22)
```

I tried the following errorformat `set errorformat='%.%#\ at\ %.%#(%f:%l)'`
, but it does not work.

So all I want it to do is jump to the file `Line.java` line 43 when I click on it.  Am I missing something in errorfomat?

Answer (score 3):

First thing I notice is that you have quotes in there. When using `set` everything after the `=` symbol is set to the value.

Since `errorformat` has spaces and backslashes my preferred way to set it is with `let` and single-quoted strings, then string concatenation so I can break it up into more easily parsed lines.

```
let &errorformat =
    \  '%*[^"]"%f"%*\D%l: %m,'
    \. '"%f"%*\D%l: %m,'
    \. '%-G%f:%l: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once,'
    \. etc.
```

So in your case it's a lot easier, let's just try it like this:

```
let &errorformat = '%.%# at %.%#(%f:%l)'
```

However you could get really fancy with multiline strings, using %E and its friends to collapse those error lines down into just the relevant info in your quickfix window but I still find that to be a bit fiddly.

Comment: If you want to try the `set` version out though, just remove the quotes from the one in the OP. You'll still need the backslashes before the spaces though.